# Problema con maven exec plugin: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, maven, windows10

Estoy generando un jar con maven y me gustaría correrlo usando maven pero obtengo un error.

Esta es mi configuración del plugin en el *pom*:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-jar</argument>
                                <argument>target/farmacia-${project.version}-jar-with-depencencies.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

La cual la aprendí de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26448245/6999690).

Al correr el comando `mvn install exec:exec -X` obtengo la ruta del jar mientras hace el install como

```
Building jar: C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\farmacia\target\farmacia-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Y la ejecución del exec me da la traza:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = [-jar, target/farmacia-1.0-jar-with-depencencies.jar]
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\farmacia
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) executable = java
[DEBUG]   (f) failWithEmptyArgument = true
[DEBUG]   (f) failWithNullKeyOrValueInEnvironment = true
[DEBUG]   (f) longClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: xoxefdp.github.com:farmacia:1.0 @ C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\farmacia\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@376e7531
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [java, -jar, target/farmacia-1.0-jar-with-depencencies.jar]
```

> Error: Unable to access jarfile target/farmacia-1.0-jar-with-depencencies.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tonto de mí, me equivoqué escribiendo el nombre del jar

```
target/farmacia-${project.version}-jar-with-depencencies.jar
```

Debería de ser

```
target/farmacia-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```