# Ejecutar proyecto Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Por cada modificacion en spring hago lo siguiente:

```
mvn clean package
```

esa instruccion tarda 1 min (lo cual es mucho)

luego ejecuto el jar que fue empaquetado en la carpeta target

```
java -jar nombreDelJar.jar
```

Debo ejecutar estas instrucciones cada vez que hago cambios? no hay otra manera que sea mas rapida?

Comment: Si usas un IDE como Eclipse, y lanzas la aplicación desde el mismo, los cambios en el código que hagas se pueden aplicar "en caliente": no tienes ni que parar la ejecución de la aplicación para ello y podrás depurarla fácilmente.

Comment: @PabloLozano  uso intellij idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mvn clean package
```

es

```
mvn clean
```

seguido de

```
mvn package
```

Como su nombre indica, `clean` borra todas las clases generadas en la compilación (básicamente el directorio `target`).

`package` hace todos los pasos de la compilación hasta el empaquetado. Si un módulo no se ha modificado, no lo recompila.

Al hacer el `clean` fuerzas a que te recompile todo el proyecto, mientras que si solo haces `mvn package` solo te recompilará los módulos afectados.

Que eso te haga el proceso más rápido dependerá de como hayas estructura el programa en módulos.

UPDATE: Si lo que quieres es ejecutar desde Maven, no es una funcionalidad que venga por defecto pero hay un plugin para eso:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
   <configuration>
       <mainClass>es.x-rw.Main</mainClass>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

(dentro de build->plugins)

Por desgracia, no parece que la página web oficial (https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) esté levantada (aunque igual es problema de mi conexión corporativa) así que no puedo dar la configuración exacta.

Así puedes hacer:

```
mvn package exec:exec
```

Para hacer primero el package y luego ejecutar el *goal* `exec` del plugin `exec.

Si quieres que se ejecute todo como parte del ciclo de vida de maven, tendrás que asociar el plugin a una fase del ciclo de vida mediante el elemento `<execution>`; por ejemplo puedes verlo [en castellano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221485/problema-con-maven-exec-plugin-unable-to-access-jarfile) o [en inglés pero mejor explicado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven).

Y si todo eso falla, siempre puedes hacer un .bat o un .sh :-p

Comment: debo levantar el .jar cada vez que haga el empaquetado ?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con `mvn spring-boot:run` para ejecutar la aplicación.

Comment: Deberías explicar qué hace ese comando y cómo soluciona el problema

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que necesites crear el jar debes ejecutar esos comandos.

Aquí te dejo el siguiente comando que se demora menos, ya que no ejecuta los test o no busca que existan:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```